# Why apache2 isn't showing my css file, but when i open the local file it works?

Tags: html, css, apache2

im very new using html and css, my problem is that when I link my css file at the begin of the html, like this

```
<link type="text/css" href="../html/doc/ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

But when i try to execute the html file that i have inside my /var/www/html directory, there is no problem, the page is working, but when I run it on apache2, seems that its not detecting my css file

PD: Im using linux

Hope you all can help me!

Comment: You could try to view whether there is any error in the console tab or try to verify the path is  correct.

Comment: the `../html` at the beginning of the path is probably the cause of the problem. Try using `/doc/ui.css` instead